# BLE Peripheral design on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, peripherals

I am working on a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) project which needs iPhone to act as a peripheral device. I am using [BLEManager](https://github.com/Hassaniiii/BLEManager) to deal with *CoreBluetooth* related jobs, which includes good implementations for both *Central* and *Peripheral* mode.

**Question**:

I don't have any idea about design patterns and best practices of a peripheral's architecture. There is no pattern for the definition of Services and Characteristics. It seems I can choose one of the following patterns:

- define multiple services, with one *read/write/notify* characteristic
- define one service, with some *read/write/notify* characteristics
- define one service, one characteristic for *read/write/notify*, and extract commands from the characteristic updated value

Which one shall I choose?

**Implementation**

Here are some parts of my peripheral implementation using [BLEManager](https://github.com/Hassaniiii/BLEManager):

```
let peripheralServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
let nameCharacteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")

var CharactersticArray = [MyCharacterstic]()

characteristic.uuid = nameCharacteristicUUID
characteristic.value = nil
characteristic.permission = [.writeable, .readEncryptionRequired]
characteristic.property = [.write, .read, .notify]
CharactersticArray.append(characteristic)

Peripheral.instance().service_UUID = peripheralServiceUUID
Peripheral.instance().service_characteristics = CharactersticArray
Peripheral.instance().localName = "iPhone"
Peripheral.instance().startAdvertising()
```

Comment: Your Question section does not include any question. If you want to know the best design, number two seems good.

Comment: @Emil I just edited the question section. I couldn't find any appropriate documentation about this pattern, could it decrease connection performance?